# Salesforce Row Formula using TODAY

Tags: salesforce

I tried this formula but got an error
IF(LAST_UPDATE>TODAY-90,"Red","Green")

How can you use the TODAY Option in the formula

IF(LAST_UPDATE GT (TODAY()-90),"Red","Green")

Comment: Your are missing the parenthesis: TODAY()

Comment: tried this and still get error missing )

Comment: IF(LAST_UPDATE GT TODAY()-90,'Red','Green')

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parenthesis: TODAY(). See [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_today.htm&type=5).

Comment: this did not work either
IF(LAST_UPDATE GT TODAY()-90,'Red','Green')

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios here :

If field type is `DateTime` we need to convert it to `Date`, formula becomes :

```
IF( DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate) >  TODAY() - 90, "RED" , "GREEN" )
```

If field type is `Date` formula becomes :

```
IF(  Date_Field__c  >  TODAY() - 90, "RED" , "GREEN" )
```

Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_using_date_datetime.htm